# How to use a class as a parameter to a second class

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming, I would like to create a class that takes the User as a 'value' field :

```
//some import
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;
    private String email; }
```

I want to create a class that has two parameters, a key and a value, value represented by the User himself. How can such a thing be created?

Comment: You just write `private User value;`.  There's nothing particularly different.

Comment: What do you mean by a "value field"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to achive is just definiting your User class as instance member of another class, which may also contain more members, in your case a key. That is a classic thing in OO programmig, not only in Java.

Here is just a simple example of what you can do.
 As per standard Java programming, I implemented the getter and setter methods in each class, so to give access to the private members:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class User implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;
    private String email;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAge() {
       return age;
    }  

    public void setAge(String age) {
       this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
       return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

public class KeyUser {
     private String key;
     private User user;

    public KeyUser(String key, User user) {
        this.key = key;
        this.user = user;
    }


    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```